# Teechart Axis Item Modification of X axis Item

Tags: activex, teechart

Can anyone let me know how I can modify the X-Axis Point Value Pro-grammatically.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want change the X values in runtime you can do something as next:

```
For i = 0 To TChart1.Series.Count

    For j = 0 To TChart1.Series(i).Count
     TChart1.Series(i).XValues(j) = j + 3
    Next j
Next i
```

Could you tell us if previous help you?

I hope will helps.

Thanks,

Comment: Actually for me I x-axis I am getting position Number, I want to replace it with Text

Comment: @AkshayBhalla in that case you probably need to set axis labels style: TChart1.Axis.Bottom.Labels.Style = talText

Comment: Actually I added the Items to particular location along with the text it worked for me.Thanks